# Ubercart Ajax change attributes on checkout

Tags: 7, ubercart

I want to change the Product Attributes on checkout page by ajax. But when I save it by `uc_order_product_save()` in my ajax request and go to the preview step the attributes are gone.

It seems that preview step retrives the $order from form storage but not mine saved order. It is here:

```
function uc_cart_checkout_form_validate($form, &$form_state) {
$order = $form_state['storage']['order'];
```

How can I access to the storage order object in form to save attributes?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the best/proper way to do it, but I have manipulated product attributes in

`function uc_cart_view_form($form, &$form_state, $items = NULL)`

it is located in uc_cart.module

$items is filled with products and you can loop through and review/assign attributes.

Comment: But how can I Access this from my module when I call Ajax request?

Comment: yourmodule_view_form() should work.

Comment: but I want to do this on checkout page: User send AJAX to my module, module set the attributes and when user go to PREVIEW section attributes send by ajax shoud be saved. So I don't know how to do this in your way, but thanks for reply.